# How do i setup multiple mariadb in one single VM using Galera Cluster?

Tags: mariadb, galera

How do i setup multiple mariadb server in one single VM using Galera Cluster?
If configuration links are available please share me?
I have searched in galera website its says add the nodes into cluster and not the adding the multiple mariadb server into cluster

Comment: Different Ports.  Why not have multiple VMs?

Comment: Rick James which is advisable multiple Vm or in single VM?

Comment: It does not matter a lot.  However, since VMs exist to isolate things, that makes more sense.  Meanwhile, there is virtually no advantage in putting all Galera nodes of a cluster on a single server, regardless of the number of VMs involved.  Are you just experimenting?  Or will this be a production cluster?

Comment: Rick James sounds good, not experimenting yes will be a production cluster

Answer (score 1):

Analysis of having 3 Galera nodes in a single server,

- All 3 in a single VM
- One in each of 3 VMs
- No VMs

Notes:

- Galera provides crash protection -- if a node goes down due to hardware failure, the other nodes continue serving the database needs.  Not so with all of them sharing the same server and disk(s).
- By having multiple instances of MySQL (whether as Galera nodes or not), you can make better use of CPUs.  But, since MySQL rarely needs all of the available CPU, I see no advantage in this configuration.
- Each instance uses some RAM for static things -- 3 instances leads to 3 copies of such.  Other things (eg, caches) scale with RAM size.
- No advantage in networking.
- (There may be other reasons why there is virtually no difference between a single instance and multiple instances.)

Comment: I used to use this tutorial for creating a MariaDB cluster to testing. I agree that for the production environment, DB cluster should be installed on different VMs/machines.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mariadb-on-ubuntu-18-04-servers

Comment: @TrầnKimDự - Good.  I hope it goes well.  For testing, I would opt for 3 VMs and different Ports.  But the number of VMs (0,1,3) should not matter much for testing.